# How to reset date to a new date?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my modules.ts DOB has a type of Date and in order to reset that in component.ts inside the resetForm method block, I cant pass string as I did for FirstName and LastName. Could you please help me with how to fix this? I have searched but didn't find any solution. However, this is my first angular code. Please help.

student-detail.modules.ts

```
    export class StudentDetail {
    Id :number;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    DOB: Date;}
```

student-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentDetailService } from 'src/app/shared/student-detail.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-detail',
  templateUrl: './student-detail.component.html',
  styles: []

})
export class StudentDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  datafromService:any;
  constructor(private service:StudentDetailService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.datafromService = this.service.formData;
  }
  resetForm(form?: NgForm){
  if (form != null)
    form.resetForm();
   this.service.formData = {
    Id :0,
    FirstName  :'',
    LastName :''
    DOB:  
   }
 }
```

}

Comment: I just set DOB: new Date() . I'm not sure if this will work yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to reset to current date time, you can use
new Date();

if you want to vanish from UI to display,  you can assign undefined or Block in UI using Ngif if you tried to format the Date in UI.